# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload Cannot Download the Image File and Cannot Upload a Bigger Size of Image

Tags: download, upload, jquery-file-upload

First of all , Apologize to my poor english .

So my project is plain php and mysql. and i implemented this awesome plugin which is the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload (using this tutotial https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration). everything is doing good. i can upload anything.

but unlucky me i have two problems. :(

1.First i cannot download the uploaded image even though the file are stored in the DB. :(  but i can download videos,.txt and anything on microsoft office file.

2.Second i cannot upload a larger size of an image. :(
here's a screenshot
[cannot uplaod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7yHi.png)

please help :( can anyone solve my problems  ??? :( very appreciated :)

*BTW i tested this only in localhost.*